# Why does EWS Managed API SyncFolderItems not return recurring appointments

Tags: calendar, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api, recurring-events

I'm using the managed API of EWS to synchronize a scheduling application with exchange calendars.  I get all normal meetings fine, but I am not getting any repeating/recurring appointments.

My code follows:

```
itemChangeCollection = _service.SyncFolderItems(
                            new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar,
                                         new Mailbox(Email)),
                            propertySet,
                            null,
                            Settings.Default.ExchangeSyncFetchCount,
                            SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems,
                            syncState);
```

What do I need to change to see the recurring appointments as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instances of recurring appointments are not "real" items in the store. They are virtual in the sense that they are calculated whenever you perform a search with a calendar view and a timeframe.

The only way to find recurring appointments is to use the FindItems method.

Comment: Actually I'm using FindItem to retrieve appointments from a room calendar with start & end date restrictions and still not receiving recurring meetings.

Comment: I just realized the reason I wasn't receiving recurring meetings even though I was using FindItem, was that I was using a search filter (I wanted to use both item view for pagination and specify a date interval). If you want to receive recurring items you can't use a search filter (at least not one with date conditions).

Answer (score 2):

`SyncFolderItems` only returns the necessary information to reconstruct a recurring serie but does not expand the individual occurrences. If you need expanded occurrences you need to use the `FindItems` method.

However, even assuming you can expand the recurrence yourself, `SyncFolderItems` alone does *not* provide all the necessary information.

`SyncFolderItems` will return a list of events with `Single` or `RecurringMaster` AppointmentType. A RecurringMaster event contains the `ModifiedOccurrences` and `DeletedOccurrences` properties. Unfortunately the items in `ModifiedOccurrences` only contains the ItemId, not the Item itself. It seems necessary to solve all exception separately to get the fields of modified occurrences. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633700(v=exchg.80).aspx):

> Each OccurrenceInfo object in the **ModifiedOccurrences** collection
>   contains four properties: **End**, **ItemId**, **OriginalStart**, and **Start**. To
>   access additional properties on the exception item, you must bind to
>   the item by using the **OccurrenceInfo.ItemId**.

```cs
foreach (OccurrenceInfo item in recurringMasterItem.ModifiedOccurrences)
{
   Appointment modifiedItem = Appointment.Bind(service, item.ItemId);
   Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + modifiedItem.Subject);
}
```

In other words, with the data you get from `SyncFolderItem` you can expand a recurrence, including time exceptions and deleted occurrences but you would have to resolve exceptions on other fields (ie. summary, body, location. etc) with additional `.Bind()` calls.

Comment: Marco, do you know how you could find out which of the ModifiedOccurrences have just been modified? (After carrying out a SyncFolderItems, and loading the ModifiedOccurrences property, it contains every occurrence that has ever been modified, rather than just the one that been modified since the last sync). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`SyncFolderItems` will give you the recurring master items, but does not expand them into occurrences. The recurring master holds the common properties for all items, the recurring pattern and a list of exceptions and deletions. This is all the information required to expand them to occurrences. Although you are supposed to call `Appointment.BindToOccurrence` to bind the properties for an individual occurrence from a recurring master based on an occurrence index. The downside is this makes an EWS call for each occurrence.